# Tilted and Misaligned Items in Optical Schemes

Tags: optics

My scientific advisor has said me to find correct and concrete **ray matrices** (ABCD (2x2) or ABCDEFGHI (3x3) or ABCDEFGHIJKL (4x4)) corresponding to **tilted** and **misaligned** optical elements such as:
mirrors (plane, spherical, parabolic, hyperbolic), two prisms playing role as a beam splitter.

Can you help me to find this information?

If you will discover the some useful information, please you will indicate a reference where you have detected it.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to some physics review, I suggest you look at a series of articles by
Anthony A. Tovar and Lee W. Casperson, "Generalized beam matrices: Gaussian beam propagation in misaligned complex optical systems," J. Opt. Soc. Am. A 12, 1522-1533 (1995)
in which they describe the ABCDGH transfer matrix formalism.

Here is the link to the first one on the Optical Society review : 
https://www.osapublishing.org/josaa/abstract.cfm?uri=josaa-12-7-1522

The formalism is a bit different than that of the classic ABCD Matrix formalism but remains quite simple. I can't help you much more as I am also currently working on this subject.

On page 9 there is a table giving some misaligned components. And the article gives a general method to calculate them and propagate beams in a general misaligned optical system

For instance, the ray matrix of a tilted mirror in the x direction is :
$$
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\beta_0 \tan \theta_x & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)
$$

Voilà,

Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

Chapter 15 of Siegman’s LASERS book deals with misaligned systems however his misalignment information is in column 3, not row 3 (Casperson’s paper). It’s also for geometric systems.  I don’t remember if he includes propagation of Gaussians through misaligned systems or not.

Comment: See chapter 19.